# Instrumentation run failed, when running halfninja android-ffmpeg-x264 ProjectTest

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-testing

I am following https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264 to create an Android project based on ffmpeg, x264.
It has two projects after building: "Project", "ProjectTest"
Apparently "Project" is not complete. 
I run "ProjectTest", the error is:

```
Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
```

Any hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Halfninja is not working on that project anymore, it is more than 2 years old already. That's why you are probably having issues, as you are probably using a newer android NDK. Try [this fork of the halfninja kit](https://github.com/edisonw/android-ffmpeg-x264), and make sure to read that manual. Also make sure you are using NDK version r5c to build it, later versions seem to have problems.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask what big difference between NDKr5c and the current version, for example r8b I am using? Personally I think there should be a big problem, and the compiling went smoothly.

Comment: The difference is 3 years in development. Android has grown very much in this time. I can't tell you exactly what's the real big difference, but for example functions got deprecated in version 6 and even removed in version 8. Also a new compiler is used and many functions are changed. This can cause the problems in newer versions.

Comment: But the ffmpeg source code is not related to Android functions. It needs Android version of gcc. Personally I think it would not make much difference.